# Can you use AJAX in an AWS Lambda/Serverless web page

Tags: .net, lambda, asp.net-ajax, serverless

In the past I've been able to be very creative using AJAX in ASP.Net websites, particularly for Intranet Applications. I've been exploring AWS Lambda/Serverless websites which have a great cost advantage, etc. Apparently you cannot use AJAX though. That makes sense and I'm pretty sure from testing. The same code works in a Docker container or run locally, which also makes sense. I'm looking into using a lambda function called by JQuery AJAX, to send an email or read a Db, which should work. Any suggestions on that would be appreciated, but what I really want to know is whether there is another approach I should take that I haven't thought of. Thanks much!